# Formatted values lose their format when passed as argument to spring message tag

Tags: java, spring-mvc, localization, jstl

Given a property file with the key

```
property.code=Text goes here {0}
```

And

```
discountPercentage = 5.0
```

When I do

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${discountPercentage / 100}" var="discount"
      type="PERCENT" minFractionDigits="1" maxFractionDigits="1" />             
<spring:message code="property.code" arguments="${discount}"  />
```

Then then the spring messge tag strips the fraction digits and the % sign and just displays 5 instead of 5.0%

Can't figure out what's going on here .. I thought it would have just worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that your local makes the formatted value `5,0%`, and not `5.0%`. And the `arguments` attribute of the spring message tag expects a comma-separated list of arguments.

Try passing no delimiter at all, or a fake delimiter:

```
<spring:message code="property.code" arguments="${discount}" argumentSeparator="${null}" />
```

or

```
<spring:message code="property.code" arguments="${discount}" argumentSeparator="" />
```

or

```
<spring:message code="property.code" arguments="${discount}" argumentSeparator="fake" />
```